# What's the shortest code to return a new array with only the first 2 elements of a given array?

Tags: java, arrays

While I was practicing Java problems on CodingBat I came across following problem statement.

**Problem**

> Given an integer array of any length, return a new array of its first 2 elements. If the array is smaller than length 2, use whatever elements are present.

**Example**

```
frontPiece([1, 2, 3]) → [1, 2]
frontPiece([1, 2]) → [1, 2]
frontPiece([1]) → [1]
```

**My solution**

```
public int[] frontPiece(int[] nums) {
    if (nums.length < 2) {
        return nums;
    }
    
    int[] myArray = new int[2];
    myArray[0] = nums[0];
    myArray[1] = nums[1];
    return myArray;
}
```

**My question**

Though I have solved this question, my solution looks a bit long. So I'm looking for shorter while still accurate other solutions. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Your solution is the best. Less memory usage, less processing. Maybe you can read deHaar solution if you want to make it shorter.

Comment: Shorter: `return nums.length < 2 ? nums : new int[] { nums[0], nums[1] };`

Comment: @MCEmperor no intention on stepping on your toes; avoid answering in comments please – thx

Comment: @IvoMori Adding this as an answer would be of less use; first, it looks much like deHaar's answer, second, this comment was written three hours after OP accepted the currently accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just want a shorter method and if returning the parameter itself when empty or with a single element is valid, then you can write this:

```
public static int[] frontPiece(int[] nums) {
    // if the argument is empty or has just a single element
    if (nums.length < 2) {
        // return the array itself
        return nums;
    } else {
        // otherwise, return a new array with the first two elements of argument
        return new int[] { nums[0], nums[1] };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a shorter alternative I'd use a Stream as in

```
public static int[] frontPiece(int[] nums) {
    return Arrays.stream(nums)
                 .limit(2)
                 .toArray();
}
```

which results in

```
frontPiece([1, 2, 3]) -> [1, 2]
frontPiece([1, 2]) -> [1, 2]
frontPiece([1]) -> [1]
frontPiece([]) -> []
```

Note that the method "streams" the elements of the input array and takes the first 2 elements using [java.util.Stream#limit​(long maxSize)](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#limit(long)) before collecting them to a new array with [toArray()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#toArray()).